# template named constructor struct omit typename

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have a class looking like

```
template <typename T> class CClass
{
    public:
        struct NamedCtor;

        CClass(T a, T b, T c);

    private:
        // data members
};

tepmlate <typename T> CClass<T>::NamedCtor : CClass<T> { NamedCtor(T x) : CClass(x, x, x) {}; };
```

With `CClass<T>::NamedCtor()` as named constructor.

This is perfectly usable if I know the template parameter when using with `CClass<int>::NamedCtor(3)`.

But if I do not know the template parameter here, for example when I'm in a template function, I have to write something like `typename CClass<T>::NamedCtor(3)` with the template parameter `T` of the function.

Is there any way to bypass this `typename` as I don't really like it?

Comment: Do Named Constructors the normal way instead of inventing new ways?
`template<class T> CClass<T> NamedCtor(T x) {return CClass<T>(x,x,x);}`  http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/named-ctor-idiom.html

Comment: Oh? What exactly is the normal way? :D
Edit: But I can't say `new CClass<T>::NamedCtor(3)` with this one, can I?

Comment: No, but you can say `new auto(CClass<T>::NamedCtor(3))` if you really have to (type must be movable, though).